# Word between humbling and flattering

Tags: single-word-requests

I was recently offered a job which I didn't think I'd be well suited to, but several people whose opinion I greatly value said they thought I'd be great at it. I'm looking for a word to describe the feeling this created in me. The closest I can say was that "I found my friends' reactions humbling". But to me humbling suggests a diminishment of one's opinion of oneself in response to an event. Perhaps "flattering" is closer, but that sounds sycophantic. It feels like there should be a better word, but I can't think of it. Any ideas?

Comment: How about "encouraging"?

Comment: i found http://janeloveswords.blogspot.co.uk/2011/12/word-spectrum.html, which doesn't answer the question, but might prove useful.

Comment: @Xanne Agreed, "encouraging" sounds like something in the right range. But it suggests I gained resolve to be able to do something, whereas I has more impressed by the opinion my friends had of me. Still, best word so far.

Comment: I was *cheered*  I was *warmed* I was touched*

Comment: @Jim Yes I think these are more on the money. Why not post as an answer?

Comment: I agree with beldaz.  @Jim should post an answer.  Why not commit to it!  Put yourself out there!  See [link] https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/387479/whats-an-adjective-for-someone-who-is-quick-to-comment-on-a-situation-but-unwil  Don't be so uninvested, Jim!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Consider "honored":

"I was honored by their consideration."

While this usage is very common, I'm having trouble coming up with a definition that exactly matches the way I'm used to seeing it used.  The closest definition I've found comes from Dictionary.com:

"[T]he privilege of being associated with or receiving a favor from a respected person, group, organization, etc."

The definition above comes closer to the meaning that I'm used to if the phrase "a favor" were replaced with "praise."

The following web links give examples of "I was honored" being used in the "humbled & flattered" sense:

https://medium.com/@jalexandertan/i-was-honored-to-receive-an-email-about-being-a-top-writer-in-the-creative-tag-today-on-medium-17f46efe4d5b

http://www.thestate.com/sports/college/university-of-south-carolina/usc-football/article18137741.html

Answer (score 0):

> "I found my friends' reactions ***reassuring***"

Collins:

> **[reassuring](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/reassuring)**
> *adjective*
>
> (of someone's words or actions) helping to make one feel less worried about something
>
> He replied, with a reassuring smile,
> 'Oh, you don't need to worry about that.'